# Invoice view in admin missing totals and footer

Tags: admin, invoice, totals, footer

I have a problem when viewing single invoice in Magento admin. When I open an invoice it is missing the totals section and the footer completely. I attached a screenshot. The grey area in the screenshot is the missing magento admin footer.

Any ideas what could cause this? I have recently upgraded from 1.5.0.1 to 1.8.1.0. There was also a problem with printing invoices, but it was solved by editing the FileParserDataSource.php and to my understanding it was because of some php version clash or something like that.

[image: invoice view missing totals and footer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was a faulty Klarna payment extension. It seems Klarna has developed a new extension (different developer) that works with 1.8.1.0. That is however not compatible with payments made with previous extension and you can't view orders that are paid with the previous extension.